# Test MassTransit state machine saga activity

Tags: masstransit, automatonymous

I'm trying to do unit tests on a custom `Activity` that I have for my MassTransit state machine saga.

It looks something like this:

```
public class UpdateActivity : Activity<UpdateState>
{
    private readonly ConsumeContext _consumeContext;
    private readonly ILogger<UpdateActivity> _logger;

    public UpdateActivity(
        ConsumeContext consumeContext,
        ILogger<UpdateActivity> logger
    )
    {
        _consumeContext = consumeContext;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) => context.CreateScope(nameof(UpdateActivity));

    public void Accept(StateMachineVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);

    public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<UpdateState> context, Behavior<UpdateState> next)
    {
        await DoStuffAsync(context.Instance);
        await next.Execute(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task Execute<T>(BehaviorContext<UpdateState, T> context, Behavior<UpdateState, T> next)
    {
        await DoStuffAsync(context.Instance);
        await next.Execute(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public Task Faulted<TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<UpdateState, TException> context, Behavior<UpdateState> next) where TException : Exception
        => next.Faulted(context);

    public Task Faulted<T, TException>(BehaviorExceptionContext<UpdateState, T, TException> context, Behavior<UpdateState, T> next) where TException : Exception
        => next.Faulted(context);
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I can mock/fake expectations for the `ConsumeContext` when writing unit tests for this class. I've tried to find something using the `InMemoryTestHarness` but can't find anything suitable.

**EDIT:**

I might as well throw this one as well in there. How do I mock `context` or run this in a test harness? So that I can unit test this Activity as well?

```
    public class UpdateActivity : Activity<UpdateState, IDataUpdatedEvent>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<UpdateActivity> _logger;

        public UpdateActivity(
            ILogger<UpdateActivity > logger
        )
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Probe(ProbeContext context) => context.CreateScope(nameof(UpdateActivity));

        public void Accept(StateMachineVisitor visitor) => visitor.Visit(this);

        public async Task Execute(BehaviorContext<UpdateState, IDataUpdatedEvent> context, Behavior<UpdateState, IDataUpdatedEvent> next)
        {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit has [test harnesses](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/testing.html#testing-using-dependency-injection) to allow state machines to be tested, along with activities using Dependency Injection.

The idea of "testing in isolation with mocks" is fairly pointless given the availability of these harnesses.

Comment: Thank you for a swift reply! I've been looking at that, but I just can't figure out how to test the Activity in isolation? I've got tests setup for the entire saga using the test harness, but I have some activities with complex logic where it would be nice to just `new Activity()` in the tests, and make assertions based on multiple different inputs.

Comment: I don't provide any way to test an activity by itself, I'm not sure what value that would provide, seems excessive vs testing it in context of the state machine.

Comment: Alright! Then I know at least. Thanks! I guess I can manipulate the state of the state machine to get the tests I want on the activity level.